# Не открываются и не создаются проекты в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Поначалу все было нормально, но как-то раз я создал проект и обнаружил, что после создания ничего не происходит. 
В правой части нет окна со всеми папками и файлами. 
На скрине все видно.[image]

Comment: Попробуйте нажать Ctrl-Alt-L

Comment: вид-> обозреватель решений